# Error: partition 0 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to determine the current offset on a topic, I run the

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell
```

Command and I get the following error, What may be going on, and how do I fix this?

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4g
Error: partition 2 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 4 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 1 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 3 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
Error: partition 0 does not have a leader. Skip getting offsets
```

Comment: Are your brokers up and running?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `kafka-topics --zookeeper host:2181 --describe --topic topic_name`?

Comment: you are right, the brokers were down. Also they output of your command showed a leader = -1

Comment: If you can create an answer, I will mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your Kafka brokers are down.

You can run

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper host:2181 --describe --topic topic_name
```

and see whether the Leader is equal to -1. If this is the case then you need to start Kafka brokers.

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```